# SQL query to return maximum value for each identifier

Tags: sql, database, select

In a table 'purchases' is a list of items bought at a 'cost' by each 'user_id'

One user can make many purchases, so there are many duplicate user_id's in the table.

What could be an SQL query that would return *only* the most expensive item that *each* user had purchased?

What is the error in the following attempt?

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(cost) 
FROM purchases
WHERE user_id 
IN (SELECT user_id FROM purchases)
```

Comment: the where clause makes no sense and you are missing a GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by each user:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(cost) 
FROM purchases
GROUP BY user_Id;
```